# Working with tExtractJSONFields in Talend

Tags: json, talend

I'am trying to extract fields from a Json file with talend. I can loop inside the array of my file but other fields have null values.

```
{
  "codeObjetStart": "KVIOPEFL",
  "codeRetour": "00",
  "libelleCodeErreur": "Traitement effectué sans erreur.",
  "resultatSdt": [
    {
      "KVIOPEFL": "0",
      "NMLIBFRA": "OPERATION SANS EFFET DE LEVIER",
      "NMLIBANG": "OPERATION WITHOUT LEVERAGE"
    },
    {
      "KVIOPEFL": "1",
      "NMLIBFRA": "LBO",
      "NMLIBANG": "LBO"
    },
    {
      "KVIOPEFL": "2",
      "NMLIBFRA": "FSA",
      "NMLIBANG": "SAF"
    },
    {
      "KVIOPEFL": "3",
      "NMLIBFRA": "CEL",
      "NMLIBANG": "CEL"
    }
  ],
  "versionObjetStart": "0"
}
```

My job is very simple, I want just to show in console.

[image]

My components configuration :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with your approach.
First, `tExtractJSONFields` doesn't support passthrough of fields (codeObjetStart, codeRetour, libelleCodeErreur, versionObjetStart). If it did support it, you wouldn't have to set a jsonpath expression for each of these fields, because you already read them in your `tFileInputJSON`. That brings us to the 2nd problem which is that jsonpath doesn't support parent operator, as per its [documentation](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

What you can do is your read your file using a component that can return it in one line. For instance, a `tFileInputDelimited` with only one column, and a row separator and field separator that are not present in your file.

Then you can use `tExtractJSONFields` with XPath to parse the fields, by setting the XPath loop query to return the children of resultatSdt.

Something like this : 
[image]

I use `tFixedFlowInput` with inline content for convenience.
And the result is:

```
.--------------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------+--------------------------.
|                                                                   tLogRow_3                                                                   |
|=-------------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------+-------------------------=|
|codeObjetStart|codeRetour|libelleCodeErreur               |versionObjetStart|KVIOPEFL|NMLIBFRA                      |NMLIBANG                  |
|=-------------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------+-------------------------=|
|KVIOPEFL      |00        |Traitement effectué sans erreur.|0                |0       |OPERATION SANS EFFET DE LEVIER|OPERATION WITHOUT LEVERAGE|
|KVIOPEFL      |00        |Traitement effectué sans erreur.|0                |1       |LBO                           |LBO                       |
|KVIOPEFL      |00        |Traitement effectué sans erreur.|0                |2       |FSA                           |SAF                       |
|KVIOPEFL      |00        |Traitement effectué sans erreur.|0                |3       |CEL                           |CEL                       |
'--------------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------+--------------------------'
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling with empty arrays- I put tjavarow and put the null check in it--see below if it helps anyone--

[image]

In the tjavarow I put--

```
if (input_row.errorArray == null || input_row.errorArray .matches("^\\[\\s*\\]$") ) {
System.out.println("errorArray is null");
output_row.errorArray = "{\"errorArray \":"+"[{ \"name\" : \"nnn\",\"value\" : \"vvv\"}]}" ; } else {
System.out.println("errorArray is NOT null");
output_row.errorArray = input_row.errorArray ;
```

}